# PostgreSQL Query To Obtain Value that Occurs more than once in 12 months

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query to return the number of users that booked a flight at least twice, but I need to identify those which have booked a flight more than once in the range of 12 months

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM sales
WHERE customer in
  (
    SELECT customer
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY customer
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  )
```

Comment: You need to add the table definition so we know what the date/timestamp field is or if there is one at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use window functions.  The simplest method is `lag()`:

```
select count(distinct customer)
from (select s.*,
             lag(date) over (partition by customer order by date) as prev_date
      from sales s
     ) s
where prev_date > s.date - interval '12 month';
```

Comment: This is clever, but doesn't the `over` clause need `order by date`?

Answer (score 2):

At the cost of a self-join, @AdrianKlaver's answer can adapt to any 12-month period.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer) FROM 
   (SELECT customer 
    FROM sales s1
    JOIN sales s2 
    ON s1.customer = s2.customer
         AND s1.ticket_id <> s2.ticket_id
         AND s2.date_field BETWEEN s1.date_field AND (s1.date_field + interval'1 year')
    GROUP BY customer
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS subquery;
```

Answer (score 0):

A stab at it with a made up date field:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM sales
WHERE customer in
  (
    SELECT customer
    FROM sales
    WHERE date_field BETWEEN '01/01/2019' AND '12/31/2019'
    GROUP BY customer
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  )
```